# Translation of a Chinese Bön book about Dzogchen

Tags: chinese-buddhism, dzogchen, bon

I am looking for a translation in english (or french) of the following book in Chinese Mandarin:

大圆满前行法海

It is a book in the Bön tradition about Dzogchen.

Comment: The "海" here corresponds to "Ocean of (+ blah blah blah)", just like the Tsongkhapa's work "Ocean of "+"reasoning" corresponds to "正理"+"海".

Answer (score 1):

I coudn't find a translation, but from what I gather from the title:

- 大圆满 Dzogchen
- 前行 forward, advance
- 法海 Fa-Hai

[法海 Fa-Hai](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fahai) was a Chan monk in the Tang dynasty, but is also the name of a Sino-Tibetan Lama (1920-1991) who studied both Chan and Dzogchen. Monica Esposito wrote a book in English on this blending of disciplines:

[The Zen of Tantra: Tibetan Great Perfection in Fahai Lama's Chinese Zen Monastery](http://universitymedia.org/Tantra.html)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is the book probably : https://sanxuezang.com/book/7571
Use the website https://www.deepl.com to translate.

Answer (score 0):

大圆满前行法海 is not a Bon text. It's either a Nyingma Buddhist text or a Chinese Ch'an Buddhist text.

Here is a Chinese site that has information about 大圆满前行法海 and its author, but it's in Chinese. You will need to use a translator to read it.

https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E5%A4%A7%E5%9C%86%E6%BB%A1%E5%89%8D%E8%A1%8C%E6%B3%95%E6%B5%B7/15454540

The author is 孜珠.丁真祖普俄色活佛.

The publisher is > 宗教文化出版社

Publication date: July 2013

The book covers > the purpose of learning Buddhism, how to listen to the Dharma, how to find a guru (teacher), and the Dharma knowledge of Yong Zhongben's practice.

There is a table of contents on this page as well.

Here are a few clips from the Table of Contents using Google translate.

1 Arouse Bodhichitta... 3

1.1 Four immeasurable minds... 3

1.1.1 Home... 3

1.1.2 Sad... 4

1.1.3 Kindness... 11

1.1.4 Happy... 12

1.2 Generate Bodhicitta... 14

2.1 Reflect on the purpose of studying Buddhism... 4

2.2 How to listen to Buddhism... 5

2.2.1 Qualified speakers... 6

2.2.2 The scene of listening to the Dharma... 6

2.2.3 Behaviors that should be discarded... 8

3.3.2 Hell... 42

3.3.2.1 Eight Hot Hells... 42

3.3.2.2 Eight Cold Hells... 44

3.3.2.3 Short-lived hell... 44

3.3.3 Hungry Ghost... 46

3.3.3.1 Hungry Ghosts Walking in the Earth... 46

3.3.3.2 Hungry ghosts... 47

3.4.1 Evil deeds to abandon... 62

3.4.1.1 Five poisons... 62

3.4.1.2 Ten Evil... 64

3.4.1.3 Results of negative karma... 70

3.4.2 Good deeds to practice... 76

5 Guru Yoga... 100

5.1 Praying to the merits of the guru... 100

5.2 Guru yoga rituals... 101

5.2.1 Prayer... 101

5.2.2 Seven supply... 102

5.2.3 Being blessed... 106

5.2.4 Receive empowerment... 107

5.2.5 Backward... 107

5.3 Guru Yoga sitting down and practicing... 107

~ ~ ~

You can get similar information, in English, if you read these two books.

"The Complete Nyingma Tradition from Sutra to Tantra - Books 01-10: Foundations of the Buddhist Path" by Choying Tobden Dorje

"The Union of Bliss and Emptiness Teachings on the Practice of Guru Yoga" by H. H. the 14th Dalai Lama and Thupten Jinpa